# Laravel Filter Multiple WhereIn Array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, laravel, where-in

I am trying to create a filter for an ecommerce store. A user can filter products by tags, each flavor tag is appended to an array: $tags_array

i.e.
Show me all products that contain the 'kiwi' **AND** 'menthol' tag

dd($tags_array);

```
array:2 [
  0 => "kiwi"
  1 => "menthol"
]
```

Filter section of the query

```
$query = $tags_array ? $query
 ->join('product_product_tag', 'products.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.product_id')
 ->join('product_tags', 'product_tags.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.tag_id')
 ->whereIn('product_tags.value', $tags_array) : $query;
```

-One product HasMany tags

-One tag BelongsToMany products

```
product_tags

id | value 
------------------
1  | kiwi 
2  | apple
3  | menthol 
4  | strawberry
```

**-Pivot table: product_product_tag**

```
product_product_tag

id | product_id | tag_id 
----------------------------
1  |    1       |    1
2  |    1       |    3
----------------------------
3  |    2       |    1
4  |    2       |    2
5  |    2       |    3
----------------------------
6  |    3       |    1
7  |    3       |    4
----------------------------
8  |    4       |    3
```

**PROBLEM**

Current query shows all products that have a kiwi **OR** menthol tag.

actual result: Products: 1, 2, 3, 4

expected result: Products: 1, 2

This query works correctly when only one tag is applied. How can I make this filter include **multiple** tags applied (product has kiwi tag **AND** menthol tag). A user can filter by 0,1,2,3,... tags

Is there a best practice for handling a dynamic number of tags?

**edit: I am using Laravel DB Query Builder**

**2nd edit: attempting btl's answer**

```
  $query = $tags_array ? $query
      ->join('product_product_tag', 'products.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.product_id')
      ->join('product_tags', 'product_tags.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.tag_id') : $query;
  if($tags_array) {
      foreach ($tags_array as $tag) {
          $query->where('product_tags.value', '=', $tag);
      }
  }
```

**3rd edit**: Pivoted back to the following:

```
$query = $tags_array ? $query
 ->join('product_product_tag', 'products.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.product_id')
 ->join('product_tags', 'product_tags.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.tag_id')
 ->where('product_tags.value', $tags_array) : $query;
```

This is incorrect still. Current filter returns results for the first tag found. Will keep working towards a more dynamic solution

Answer (score 0):

`whereIn('product_tags.value', $tags_array)` will match everything that has at least one of the tags in the array, hence why it's behaving as `OR`. If you need to match only products with all the selected tags, you need to set up multiple where clauses, something to the effect of:

```
$query = Product::with('tags');
foreach ($tags_array as $tag) {
     $query->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tag) {
         $q->where('id', $tag);
     });
 }
 $query->get();
```

**Edit**

```
$query = $tags_array ? $query
 ->join('product_product_tag', 'products.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.product_id')
 ->join('product_tags', 'product_tags.id', '=', 'product_product_tag.tag_id');

foreach ($tags_array as $tag) {
    $query->where('product_tags.id', '=', $tag);
}
```

Comment: Ty, I understand the logic here but my query is written using Laravel db builder. Any idea on how to convert this? I removed eloquent from the tags, sorry for any confusion

Comment: I don't think it would change too much, You'd still alias the query and then loop over the tags. Have a look at my edit and see if that works.

Comment: See my 2nd edit where I implemented your answer. This works for one flavor tag, but as soon as a second one is added, there are 0 results.